# How to convert BarCodeKit Objective-C code into Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

This is Objective-C code in [BarCodeKit](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/BarCodeKit):

```
NSError *error;
_barcodeObject = [[_barcodeClass alloc] initWithContent:_contentsTextField.text error:&error];
```

How do I convert this code to Swift?

When I tried the following in Swift, it said that I can't pass `NSError` into the function.

```
var error1 = NSError()

BCKCode39Co = BCKCode39Co.init(content: Content, error: NSError?)
```

Comment: What is `BCKCode39Co`

Comment: @RobertDresler this is objective-c class.

Comment: i'm use this class in my project for barcode generate. https://github.com/Cocoanetics/BarCodeKit

Comment: try `bckCode39Co = BCKCode39Co(content:your_text, error:&error1)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the headers for [BarCodeKit](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/BarCodeKit), I'd suggest you use the [class method](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/BarCodeKit/blob/develop/Core/Source/BCKCode39Code.h#L40):

```
+ (instancetype)code39WithContent:(NSString *)content error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
```

E.g. in Swift 4.2:

```
do {
    let barcode = try BCKCode39Code.code39(withContent: string) // or use rendition with `withModulo43` parameter
    imageView.image = UIImage(barCode: barcode, options: nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: thanx bro, where to find this method tell me. Because here many class so how to use?

Comment: I found this looking at the [class hierarchy](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/BarCodeKit/Classes/BCKCode39Code.html).

Comment: I chose this class method because the inclusion of this [deprecated method declaration for `initWithContents:`](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/BarCodeKit/blob/develop/Core/Source/BCKCode.h#L158) is causing problems for the Swift bridging. That line really should bear some indication that it's not available in Swift (see https://github.com/Cocoanetics/BarCodeKit/pull/7, which introduces `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`) and when you do that, Xcode can correctly determine the correct method to call. With that done, you can do things like `let barcode = try BCKEAN8Code(content: string)`.

Comment: Thnx bro for pull to request in github.